# What are the different possible ways to reduce the time complexity of vector array implementing stack in the given program..?

Tags: c++, vector, stack, time-complexity

Stack implementation using vector takes so much time to run if i run with 10^5 test cases.so i am just looking for different ways by which i can make my code efficient so that this program run fast enough in the huge range of test cases and as i know that each vector function have a huge cost. like if i am using `stack.size()` then it iterate the whole vector so it is inefficient to use that but i think there is no alternative way cause you have to iterate through the vector array.I just need to make my code more optimized and need suggestion in that. 
Please help me out with this.
Thank you.

```
`vector<int> stack;

void push()
{
    int element;
    cin>>element;
    stack.push_back(element);

}

void pop()
{
    if(stack.empty())
    {
        return;
    }

    stack.pop_back();

}

void max_element()
{
    int max = stack[0];
    for(int i=0; i<stack.size();i++)
    {
        if(max < stack[i])
        {
            max = stack[i];
        }
    } 
       cout<<max<<endl;


}

int main() {  
    int t,n;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n;
        switch (n)
        {
            case 1:push();
                break;

            case 2:pop();
                break;

            case 3:max_element();
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your current algorithm for `max_element()` takes O(n) time... if half your switch case is on case `3`. You basically have an O(N^2) performance which is really bad on an input size of anywhere close to `10^5`. You can improve this by having `max_element` run in O(1) time. You need to do this by storing an extra element or an extra stack of minimum elements

Comment: There is two way do it 1) Use extra memory set  as tracking storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a implementation using set

**set** is used to store values from greater to smaller ,
 so the first value is always the max value .O(1)

when there is push in vector item is added to the set as well

when there is pop , item is erased from set

Set of input

```
6 test case 

1
10

1
43

1
12

1
55

2

3
43
```

max value is 43

Full code implementation

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

std::multiset<int,std::greater<int> > settrack;
vector<int> stack;

void push()
{
    int element;
    cin>>element;
    stack.push_back(element);
    settrack.insert(element);

}

void max_element()
{
    auto max = settrack.begin();
    cout<<*max<<endl;

}

void pop()
{
    if(stack.empty())
    {
        return;
    }
    settrack.erase(settrack.find(stack.back()));
    stack.pop_back();

}

int main() {
    int t,n;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cout<<"1:push  2:pop 3:max_element "<<endl;
        cin>>n;
        switch (n)
        {
            case 1:push();
                break;

            case 2:pop();
                break;

            case 3:max_element();
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
6
1:push  2:pop 3:max_element 
1
10
1:push  2:pop 3:max_element 
1
43
1:push  2:pop 3:max_element 
1
12
1:push  2:pop 3:max_element 
1
55
1:push  2:pop 3:max_element 
2
1:push  2:pop 3:max_element 
3
43
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

PS: Part of solution credit goes to **Conrad Parker** see comment

Comment: Set won't handle duplicates, eg. if you replace 55 with 43 then the returned max will be 12, even though there is still one element 43 in the stack.

Comment: @conrad Parker set won't have duplicates ? see reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

Comment: 6
1:push  2:pop 3:max_element 
1
10
1:push  2:pop 3:max_element 
1
43
1:push  2:pop 3:max_element 
1
12
1:push  2:pop 3:max_element 
1
12
1:push  2:pop 3:max_element 
2
1:push  2:pop 3:max_element 
3
43
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: @ConradParker see the above result  1 12 12 added instead of 55 still max is 43

Comment: Set won't store duplicates, you want to use multiset instead. With set, if you insert 10 43 12 43, then pop, the max will be 12, whereas the stack will contain [10, 43, 12] and should have a max of 43.

Comment: @ConradParker got you ..perfect

Comment: So change the definition of settrack to use std::multiset, and change pop() to do settrack.erase(settrack.find(stack.back())); so that only one copy of the value is erased.

Comment: Indeed @ConradParker you are correct my previous code can run all the test cases but lags in time constraints and Hariom your code fulfill the requirements of time constraint but cannot pass all the test cases because it cannot have duplicates..

Comment: @SamarthSaxena now the code changed as per Conrad suggestion ..have a look at edited code

Comment: @SamarthSaxena now the code changed as per Conrad suggestion ..have a look at edited code

Comment: @SamarthSaxena Approve the answer if it helped

Comment: It's an acceptable solution, but not really a good one yet. Inserting into a set, as well as finding any specific element other than min or max is logarithmic run time complexity. The reference solution for this problem is to store pairs of <value,max> in the vector instead, as that's truly constant complexity for all 3 operations.

Comment: @Ext3h Would love to see your solution ..OP was specific on searching for max ..why would he search for some other element

Comment: The pop operation is searching the set for an arbitrary element, and same goes for the push operation when you are inserting into the set. It's part of how multiset is implemented internally. I can post the solution later.

Answer (score 1):

Constant time solution for all 3 of `pop`, `push` and `max_element` operations:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

struct frame {
    int value;
    int max;
};

void push(std::vector<struct frame> &stack)
{
    int element;
    std::cin >> element;
    stack.push_back({
        element,
        std::max(stack.back().max, element)
    });
}

void pop(std::vector<struct frame> &stack)
{
    if(stack.size() <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    stack.pop_back();
}

void max_element(const std::vector<struct frame> &stack)
{
    std::cout << stack.back().max << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // Don't use global static variables, whenever possible make it local.
    std::vector<struct frame> stack;
    // Need to have a "default" maximum on the stack, use the lowest possible integer.
    stack.push_back({
        std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
        std::numeric_limits<int>::min()
    });
    int t,n;
    std::cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        std::cin>>n;
        switch (n)
        {
        case 1:
            push(stack);
            break;

        case 2:
            pop(stack);
            break;

        case 3:
            max_element(stack);
            break;
        }
    }
    // Expect that only the "default" frame is left on the stack.
    return stack.size() == 1 ? 0 : -1;
}
```

This is a typical example of "dynamic programming". Compute and store partial solutions when you can get them for free, so you can reuse them to compute a future result.

In the case, storing the maximum on the stack for each single frame is a constant overhead in the `push` operation (you will barely even be able to measure it), but allows to compute the `max_element` in a constant time as well.

No matter which, or how many elements the `stack` already contains, or how often `max_element` is called, the performance does not degrade.